# Recommend replacement for TP-Link TL-WA901ND v2

Tags: access-point

I have a TP-Link TL-WA901ND v2 router that is being used as an access point. It is showing its age and sometimes it disconnects or the network slows down considerably.

I'm considering replacing this device with a more modern and more capable device, but don't want to overspend in buying something that would be overkill. So much time has passed since the issue of my device that it is difficult to compare specifications.

Due to local availability, I would prefer a replacement from one of the following brands: TP-Link or Ubiquity.

I would like the new device to have an improved speed and possibly improved range.

What would you recommend?

Answer (score 2):

Having used it for the last 5 years, I would recommend the Ubiquity Unifi Security Gateway - USG-3P.

[image]

It has one WAN port and two LAN ports.

The only gotcha is that if you enable IDS (Intrusions detection/Prevention System) then the throughput goes down.